# How to parse moment.duration with multiple formats

Tags: parsing, momentjs, duration

I have the following input formats of the time

```
const formats = ['m:ss', 'mm:ss', 'H:mm:ss', 'HH:mm:ss'];
```

and I need to extract the number of seconds using moment.js.

I tried this:

```
const myMoment = moment('03:30', formats);
const totalSeconds = myMoment.asSeconds();
```

and this

```
const formats = ['m:ss', 'mm:ss', 'H:mm:ss', 'HH:mm:ss'];
const duration = moment.duration('03:50', formats);
const totalSeconds = duration.asSeconds();
```

but neither works